# How should I remove the title of the document from an embed Google Sheet?

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I'm hoplessly trying to remove the title of my Google Sheet that is embed on my webpage (by Webnode). I've already tried adding &chrome=false to the link, but then it doesn't work (it says that it can't load the document). Where should I put that in the code? Or what's the way of removing the title?

Here's the code:

```
<iframe width="90%" height="420" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRERjtiSWcFvm5gtyyfJbsb83RD3Du9-hUCWwMiSo4AaFDEbe1nyn_vFYVsyE5XqryBdvMsNY3EV6Vs/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha, I resolved my second issue in a row. :D
For some reason, webnode added that "&amp" something at the end of "chrome=false", and now it is working!

```
<iframe width="90%" height="420" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRERjtiSWcFvm5gtyyfJbsb83RD3Du9-hUCWwMiSo4AaFDEbe1nyn_vFYVsyE5XqryBdvMsNY3EV6Vs/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;&amp;chrome=false&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```