# Remove footer when embedding googlesheet in webpage

Tags: google-sheets

In this post I got the solution to remove the header while embedding (part) of a googlesheet:
[How should I remove the title of the document from an embed Google Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68704632/how-should-i-remove-the-title-of-the-document-from-an-embed-google-sheet).
Thank you for that.
But is it also possible to remove the footer.
In my embed container I embed a range of a sheet from a file.
The header shows the name of the googlesheet (removed with chrome=false), the footer shows the name of the sheet. Can I remove that to?

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion:

Change `widget=true` to `widget=false`. This will hide the sheet's name in the footer. Your embed link should like this, for example:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/[sheet-id]/pubhtml?gid=[gid-id]&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

### Reference:

- [Edit embedded sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en#zippy=%2Cedit-embedded-spreadsheets)

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks. Is there also a way to remove the grey scroll bar?

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the scrollbar, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855471/resize-iframe-content-according-to-iframe-width-height) might help. You'd have to play with the `width=`, `height=`, and `scale()` values to achieve your desired results. Please note that you may need to adjust the iframe's dimensions as well to fit the content.

Comment: Is there also an option to send formatting rules (color, size of font...)

Comment: I'm not aware of any, unfortunately. There doesn't seem to be an option of modifying the sheet's formatting rules when embedding it. You'd have to change the format on the Sheets file itself. I suggest posting this as a separate question though so that more knowledgeable members of the community can contribute and provide their insights.